# Reduce read write delays in specific database setup

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a database with a large table with 15 columns (type double). It contains a large amount of data (~ 100 rows of data for every second. Holds 3 days of data). I also have a real-time program that adds data every second. Each row is uniquely indexed by a serial type.

My requirements are:

- The latest available data (~300 s of data) on the table is required to be displayed on a GUI monitor tool.
- Also a cleanup program needs to remove data that is older than 3 days from the table and write it to a file.

When I run this setup for over a day, I notice my query delays are increasing with time (upto 30 ms on insert and upto 1.5 s on fetch ). How do I keep my delays constant and below 1 s in both cases ). I am interested in a solution that is scalable

I am currently using PostgreSQL database. The insert and cleanup program are written in C using the ODBC driver and the GUI toolkit is web based with PHP/Apache as the back-end.

Comment: That unique index is going to be a pain point for you. Is it strictly required?

Comment: Presumably, you have a time column. Have you indexed it? And showing the exact queries and execution plans would help...

Comment: Unless the data is accessed in ways you are not telling us, then I don’t know if a database is the best solution.  
I am thinking of a message queue that is forked, with one output going to the GUI and anther going to a process that write the data to files.  The GUI can keep the last 300 secs in memory.

Comment: @CraigRinger No, the index is not strictly required, can manage without it.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic There is a time column but its not the default timestamp type. It is stored as 'Modified Julian Days' and is of type double

Comment: @IanRingrose Well, that idea was considered, but since we have a Web based toolkit, message queue becomes quite a  complicated issue. We will need another program to read from the queue and store as files so that it can be served by PHP

Comment: @AndyStowAway OK. Ensure it is indexed and use the [naked field](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/functions) in your WHERE clause (as opposed to applying a function to it). But we shouldn't have to guess these things - please supply us with the relevant DDL, query and its execution plan.